# How do I use a patternset to filter a list of files?

Tags: ant

This seems like something that should be obvious, but I don't think it is.  Given:

- a space-delimited list of files (or comma-delimited, etc.)
- a `<patternset>` of whitelisted patterns

How do I come up with a `<fileset>` that contains all of the files in the list that match the whitelisted pattern?

Getting a list of files from the list is easy enough:

```
<patternset id="the-patternset" includes="${list.of.files}" />
<fileset id="the-fileset" dir="${basedir}">
    <patternset refid="the-patternset" />
</fileset>
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="the-filelist" refid="the-fileset"/>
<echo>fileset: ${the-filelist}</echo>
```

…will happily produce a fileset with all of the files in `${list.of.files}`.  But adding a filter of sorts:

```
<patternset id="the-filter">
    <include name="includeme/**/*.java" />
    <exclude name="excludeme/**/*.java" />
</patternset>

<patternset id="the-patternset" includes="${list.of.files}" />
<fileset id="the-fileset" dir="${basedir}">
    <patternset refid="the-patternset" />
    <patternset refid="the-filter" />
</fileset>
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="the-filelist" refid="the-fileset"/>
<echo>fileset: ${the-filelist}</echo>
```

…will list a union of the patternsets—i.e., all files that match either `the-filter` *or* `the-patternset`.

How do I produce a fileset containing files that are in `${list.of.files}` *and* match `the-patternset`?

Comment: Did you get a working solution for this Jun-Dai?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potted example.  Create two filesets (or perhaps filelists) one from each of your patternsets.  I'll just use fixed lists here:

```
<property name="list.1" value="a,b,c" />
<property name="list.2" value="b,c,d" />

<fileset dir="." id="set.1" includes="${list.1}" />
<fileset dir="." id="set.2" includes="${list.2}" />
```

Then use the [`<intersect>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#intersect) resource collection to get the required 'overlap' set:

```
<intersect id="intersect">
    <resources refid="set.1"/>
    <resources refid="set.2"/>
</intersect>
```

Most Ant tasks will allow you to use a resource collection in place of a simple fileset.

Comment: That allows me to print the intersection, but how do I then convert the intersection back into a fileset?  PMD, for example, will not tolerate a resource collection.

Comment: There's various ways, but why not do what you have already done, i.e. make a patternset from the intersect list, then a fileset from the patternset?